# Testing/Debugging a Phonegap iOS app in Windows

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, phonegap

I have a simple app, created using PhoneGap [Build]. Signed up for a developer account and got the app actually signed & installed in a test iPhone I borrowed.  The app works perfectly on Android, and testing it in a browser. However on an iPhone, it hangs at the 'intro' screen.

Apparently, to debug it I'd need a Mac, specifically Safari v6+ [dev tools], which isn't available for windows.

I just simply need a way to see the console / errors for what is going on. I have been searching and trying different methods for 3 days now, and have hit a dead end.

Comment: Doing just about anything with iOS requires a mac.  If you're going to support it, you'll have to buy one eventually.

Comment: Not the best method but i'm currently using the phonegap build with a certificate that allows my phone to download the IPA file generated on it and then test it... You can do almost the whole process on a windows machine however the one last stap of uploading to itunesconnect must be done on a mac.

Comment: @Gabe Sechan, that's the gist of it, but I was definitely not about to go out and buy a Mac just to debug a phonegap app.  Probably a gray area, but installing High Sierra on VMWare was quite simple and did the truck.

Comment: @Mart You are correct, but I'd already signed & installed the app.  Also, you can install the .ipa on iTunes on windows as well.  The tricky part was actually debugging the app, after it was installed, which was what the question was about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured I'd add what I ended up doing for anyone else searching for this down the road...

The easiest way to do this was to install MacOS on VMWare.  This video was particularly helpful (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3b04Da1WjBc).

Then, under the USB controller in VMWare make sure to select USB 2.0 & 'Show all'.   Then all you should have to do is enable Safari Developer Tools under preferences on your VM, plug in your phone, and you're good to go.   Was 10 times easier than every other description I found on the web.

Edit: Also, do not allow the OS to update, that will kill it.